# Http proxy for android emulator: Address familiy not supported

Tags: android-emulator, http-proxy

When running my android emulator using the `http-proxy` config I get debug output indicating an error and no traffic on my proxy.

Starting the proxy:

```
emulator @image -port 5555 -http-proxy http://localhost:8080 -debug-proxy
```

and the error

```
tcp:172.217.16.68:443(77): cannot connect to proxy: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain why but the solution is to change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`:

```
emulator @image -port 5555 -http-proxy http://127.0.0.1:8080 -debug-proxy
```